# npm build to two dist folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gatsby

I have a Gatsbyjs project and I'm trying to build into 2 different folders `public` and `production`.

The `public` folder will be used for development purposes.

I have tried `npm build ./production`. It is building into the public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite not being a common purpose, you can achieve that changing you `gatsby-node.js` via Gatsby API (`onPostBuild`):

```
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")

exports.onPreInit = () => {
  if (process.argv[2] === "build") {
    fs.rmdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "dist"), { recursive: true })
    fs.renameSync(
      path.join(__dirname, "public"),
      path.join(__dirname, "public_dev")
    )
  }
}

    exports.onPostBuild = () => {
  fs.renameSync(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), { overwrite: true })
      fs.renameSync(
        path.join(__dirname, "public_dev"),
        path.join(__dirname, "public")
      )
    }
```

In the example above, you will output in`/dist` when running `gatsby build` command.

Useful GitHub issues:

1. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/18975
2. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14703

Comment: thanks , I tried this but the issue when I run build again it give med error that the folders already exist .
```  Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/gh/Desktop/proj/public' -> '/home/gh/Desktop/proj/public_dev'
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, try overwriting the folder with  `{overwrite:true}`